# How I can validate a Django form with a model attribute?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have a Django model (ChildrenGodfather) that relates 3 other models: Child, Godfather and Edition (2012, 2013, 2014..).

When we create a new ChildrenGodfather, there is no Edition field: it automatically saves it using the latest edition, without showing it to the user (already working)

We can't have the same Child with the same Godfather in the same Edition, but we can have the same Child with the same Godfather in different Editions.

The problem is.. the is no field edition in the forms when creating, so we didn't get a way to validate the edition. So our validation is not allowing us to have Child with the same Godfather in different Editions.

You can get a working code here:

==== models.py ====

```
class Edition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Name')
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=u'Date')

class Godfather(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Name')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True, help_text=u'Is active?')

class Children(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Name')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True, help_text=u'Is active?')

class ChildrenGodfather(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Sponsorship'
        unique_together = ['child', 'godfather', 'edition']

    child = models.ForeignKey(Children, verbose_name=u'Child')
    godfather = models.ForeignKey(Godfather, verbose_name=u'Godfather')
    edition = models.ForeignKey(Edition)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if it is creating, don t need to tell edition
        if not self.pk:
            self.edition = Edition.objects.order_by('-date')[0:1].get()
        super(ChildrenGodfather, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

==== forms.py ====

```
class ChildrenGodfatherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    child = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=u'Child', queryset=Children.objects.filter(is_active=True))
    godfather = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=u'Godfather', queryset=Godfather.objects.filter(is_active=True))

    # TODO improve checking for editions
    def clean(self):
        try:
           ChildrenGodfather.objects.get(child=self.cleaned_data['child'], 
                                         godfather=self.cleaned_data['godfather'])     
            #if we get this far, we have an exact match for this form's data
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"This sponsorship already exists. Duplicated sponsorship are not allowed!")
        except ChildrenGodfather.DoesNotExist:
            #because we didn't get a match
            pass
        return self.cleaned_data
```

==== admin.py ====

```
class ChildrenGodfatherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChildrenGodfatherForm
    fields = ['child', 'godfather']
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'child', 'godfather', 'status']
    list_filter = ['child', 'godfather', 'status']
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get currently?

Comment: You really need to show the edition dropdown in the form, defaulting to the last Edition available.

Comment: It obviously won't since unique_together creates constraint on db level.. you need to remove it and migrate changes and manually check uniqueness.

Comment: @DivinusVox I am not getting any errors. It is just not working as expected.

Comment: @SteveK I need to not show it. System requirements.. and I really think it is possible to not show.

Comment: @mariodev I don't think you understood it right.. this constraint is needed. I can't have in my database 2 columns with the same Children, Godfather and Edition.

Comment: Your constraint gives very few choices : you will need to hide the edition field only if the form instance is None or has no id. But even then, once you've created a ChildrenGodfather instance (with the latest edition by default), you will **absolutely** need to be able to choose the edition on subsequent instance creations. Or else it will conflict.
Another idea is that you can hide the edition field on object creation, but show it on object edition. This would greatly mitigate the catch-22 situation.
Tell me if this seems fine

Comment: @SteveK I go with your second option. The idea is to make it simple to create.. never needing to select the Edition. When the person is editing is reasonable to have this field shown.

This is a system for Christmas, so people will always be inserting sponsorships for that year (the latest Edition) ;)

Comment: I see :)
Please have a look at my edited answer, I think it may become an accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the **init** method of ChildrenGodfatherForm to initialize default edition

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChildrenGodfatherForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if instance is not None:
        self.edition = instance.edition  # updating existing object, use its edition
    else:            
        self.edition = Edition.objects.latest('date') # creating new object, use default edition.
```

and then modify the query in clean method to use this parameter

```
ChildrenGodfather.objects.get(child=self.cleaned_data['child'], 
                             godfather=self.cleaned_data['godfather'], edition=self.edition)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but got the error: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given). I am using default admin interface, so I don't know if I can customize the configs to pass this new parameter.

Comment: Updated code above to initialize edition inside form itself using a simple query.

Answer (score 1):

```
def default_edition():
    return Edition.objects.latest('date') # or Edition.objects.order_by('-date')[0]

class ChildrenGodfather(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Sponsorship'
        unique_together = ['child', 'godfather', 'edition']

    child = models.ForeignKey(Children, verbose_name=u'Child')
    godfather = models.ForeignKey(Godfather, verbose_name=u'Godfather')
    edition = models.ForeignKey(Edition, default=default_edition)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildrenGodfather, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ChildrenGodfatherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChildrenGodfatherForm
    fields = ['child', 'godfather', 'edition']
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'child', 'godfather', 'edition', 'status']
    list_filter = ['child', 'godfather', 'edition', 'status']
```

if you want the Edition field to be hidden on object creation, but visible on object edition, you can add this method to your `ChildrenGodfatherAdmin` class:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj is None:
        self.exclude = ["edition"]
    form = super(ChildrenGodfatherAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    return form
```

Comment: I like your default_edition method, makes the code more readable. I added this function to the Edition model to make it more elegant.